# Immutable some view body variable/opaque return in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

In Swift 5.1 there are opaque types. I see that e.g. `body` is a required protocol variable. It's contract is defined as follows:

```
var body: Self.Body { get }
```

It means we should be able to mark body as immutable (no `set`). How must this be done? Is it possible for opaque variable types to be immutable? I tried:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

    init() {
        body = AnotherView(body: Text(""))
    }

    let body: some View
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var body: Text
}
```

But I get the error that `AnotherView` must be casted to `some View`. After doing that, I get the error:

> 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties
>   and subscripts and the return type of functions

Am I able to conform to `View` with immutable `body` variables which are of type `some View` (not marking it explicit as `AnotherView`)? `AnotherView` is `some View`, I don't understand why I can't just assign the instance of `AnotherView` to `body`. I want to remain flexible and not expose the actual implementation type of body outside the struct, but I want to initialize it directly inside the initializer (because I am passing in values inside the initializer, making more properties and use them in the body property is verbose).

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no setter, any `body` implementation that is a value type will be immutable. The `var` just means that `body` is lazily evaluated, not that it is mutable. You *could* declare `let body`, but, as you point out, this exposes the underlying `View`'s implementation:

```swift
public struct StaticTextView : View {
    public let body: Text

    public init(string: String) {
        self.body = Text(string)
    }
}
```

One way you could fix this would be to have `body` just return an internal private value, like so:

```swift
public struct StaticTextView : View {
    private let textView: Text
    public var body: some View { textView }

    public init(string: String) {
        self.textView = Text(string)
    }
}
```

However, you should bear in mind that `body` is designed to be run dynamically whenever any of the bound state changes, and if you want to assign your view to a constant, nothing in that view hierarchy could be bound to any dynamic state. For example, this would not be possible:

```swift
struct DynamicStepperView : View {
    @State var stepperValue = 1

    var body: some View {
        Stepper(value: $stepperValue, in: 1...11, label: { Text("Current Value: \(stepperValue)") })
    }
}
```

If your primary concern is preventing the leaking of implementation details of your view hierarchy, note that the opaque return type of `some View` is indeed opaque to any clients of the code, and they will not be able to see any of the details of the underlying implementation other than that it is *some*thing that conforms to the `View` protocol.